# Cannot find symbol HibernateUtil

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I'm following the tutorial on Hibernate as seen [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html) and in my 'FilmHelper' class I'm trying to get a Session object like so:

```
package dvdrental;

import org.hibernate.Session;

public class FilmHelper {

    Session session = null;

    public FilmHelper() {
        this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    }

}
```

But I'm getting a 'cannot find symbol' error stating that it cannot find 'HibernateUtil' ... Has something changed in the way you obtain a session in Hibernate, is the tutorial out of date, or have I done something wrong?

Comment: Which Hibernate version are you using?

Comment: Another question: what are you intending to use the session for? Do you have access to the entity manager?

Comment: @Thomas phew, all that is greek to me, this is a beginner tutorial I'm following on Hibernate so.. I don't really know what you're talking about.. Follow my link to the tutorial above and find the "Creating the FilmHelper.java Helper Class" heading.. that's where I am now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is how you should retrieve the session, especially if the `FilmHelper` instance is stored somewhere.

If you have access to an entity manager (I assume so because of the java-ee tag), you just need to do this:

```
Session s = (Session)entityManager.getDelegate();
```

**UPDATE**:

The tutorial you linked has a part "Creating the HibernateUtil.java Helper File", so maybe that's what's missing.

But please note that this is just a start. For more complex or robust solutions you should have a look at the documentation and maybe use JPA as an abstraction level.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas.. have you followed the link to the tutorial though? This really is just me asking if there's something wrong with the tutorial or imports that might be missing...

Comment: @Relborg See my update ;) However, note that it's not always the best way to just follow the tutorial steps, it's better to understand what is done and why - and often there are better ways than what a tutorial proposes, that's why you'll often get asked about what you're trying to achieve in the first place.

Comment: Noted thanks :) my plan was to get the application up and running initially and then I'll go through the code and start seeing what all is happening behind the scnenes

Comment: @Thomas if you could provide some documentation links with JPA abstraction level it'll help Thx

Comment: @PhilippeGachoud I'm not sure what exactly you need but if you're using some sort of Java EE compliant server (such as Wildfly or TomEE) you'd just have to use JPA. Documentation on JPA should be easy to find, a good start might be here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are exactly following the tutorial, check for package of HibernateUtil.java and it access i.e. whether it is public or protected.Also, check if you are missing import for HibernateUtil.java. If still issue is there, check HibernateUtil.java for any error related to library. As sometimes imported class have issue which causes cannot find alert in different class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your own class HibernateUtil as folows:

- Right-click the Source Packages node and select New > Other to open
  the New File wizard.
- Select Hibernate from the Categories list and HibernateUtil.java  (or other name) from the File Types list. Click Next.
- Type HibernateUtil (or other name) for the class name and type package name in which the class will be stored. Click Finish.

It is supposed that IDE is NetBeans.